# Why are most of the components in this app being updated every second?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code, `setInterval` updates the toggle to be `true` every second within `componentDidMount` in `App`. However, in terms of React, the toggle state is not really changing as it is constantly being set to the same value... And as I understand it, React checks the relevant state values to see if they have changed/updated before deciding whether to re-render the UI view or not. So why are any of the components being updated?

```
import React from 'react';

class Pure extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      update: props.toggle,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <strong>
        <span style={{ color: 'mediumseagreen' }}>Pure: </span>
        {new Date().getSeconds().toString()}
      </strong>
    );
  }
}

const Stateless = props => (
  <strong>
    <span style={{ color: 'orange' }}>Stateless: </span>
    {new Date().getSeconds().toString()}
  </strong>
);

class Normal1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      update: props.toggle,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <strong>
        <span style={{ color: 'dodgerblue' }}>Normal1: </span>
        {new Date().getSeconds().toString()}
      </strong>
    );
  }
}

class Normal2 extends React.Component {
  state = {
    update: this.props.toggle,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <strong>
        <span style={{ color: 'green' }}>Normal2: </span>
        {new Date().getSeconds().toString()}
      </strong>
    );
  }
}

class Normal3 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <strong>
        <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>Normal3: </span>
        {new Date().getSeconds().toString()}
      </strong>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { toggle: true };

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ toggle: true });
      // this.setState({ toggle: !this.state.toggle })
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    const { toggle } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Pure toggle={toggle} />
        <br />
        <Stateless toggle={toggle} />
        <br />
        <Normal1 toggle={toggle} />
        <br />
        <Normal2 toggle={toggle} />
        <br />
        <Normal3 />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Normally when you set a timer function like that in componentDidMount it automatically gets reloaded. It is usually a trick to reload the react app every given interval

Comment: Sure... But I am trying to understand why it updates, as React normally only updates the view if the state value has actually changed... In this case, it hasn't really changed. It's always true... So why is the view updated?

Comment: Read [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) and [Avoid Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
this.setState({ toggle: true });
```

When you set the state here you trigger a rerender in the App component. This is because your new state is a different object. Even though it has the same values(toggle: true) the object is a different one. So the render method of the App will be called and therefore the children will be rendered again.

If you do not want to update some of the children you can use a [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) or [memo hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). Basically, they are doing a shallow comparison to compare the props.

Answer (score 0):

You use a `componentDidMount()` without checking the value of the toggle, then the render will continue to run because the state value is updated even though it has the same value.
if you don't want to update because the values ​​are the same use `componentShouldUpdate()`

```
import React from "react";

class Pure extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      update: props.toggle,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <strong>
        <span style={{ color: "mediumseagreen" }}>Pure: </span>
        {new Date().getSeconds().toString()}
      </strong>
    );
  }
}

const Stateless = (props) => (
  <strong>
    <span style={{ color: "orange" }}>Stateless: </span>
    {new Date().getSeconds().toString()}
  </strong>
);

class Normal1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      update: props.toggle,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <strong>
        <span style={{ color: "dodgerblue" }}>Normal1: </span>
        {new Date().getSeconds().toString()}
      </strong>
    );
  }
}

class Normal2 extends React.Component {
  state = {
    update: this.props.toggle,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <strong>
        <span style={{ color: "green" }}>Normal2: </span>
        {new Date().getSeconds().toString()}
      </strong>
    );
  }
}

class Normal3 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <strong>
        <span style={{ color: "red" }}>Normal3: </span>
        {new Date().getSeconds().toString()}
      </strong>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { toggle: true };

  componentDidMount(){
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ toggle: true });
      // this.setState({ toggle: !this.state.toggle })
    }, 1000);
  }

  

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextState.toggle === this.state.toggle) {
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { toggle } = this.state;
  
    return (
      <div>
        <Pure toggle={toggle} />
        <br />
        <Stateless toggle={toggle} />
        <br />
        <Normal1 toggle={toggle} />
        <br />
        <Normal2 toggle={toggle} />
        <br />
        <Normal3 />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```